# how do I check multiple values in an object?

Tags: javascript

So for example you select up to 3 elements. Every time when you select an element it is stored in a array. Select `a` and `var objects = ["a"];` after that you select `b` and `var objects = ["a", "b"]`;

Now my code is working without looking for objects in array but I would like to make it working like this.

So what is doing now it gets `option` element and look for it in arrays. But every time when you select a new `option` I want to squeeze the list of searching. So if at first point it was looking only for `a` option in all possibilities now it will look for `a` and `b` where it could be `{["a","b","c"]}` or `{["a","c","b"]}` or `{["c","b","a"]}` etc.

```
var filtered = s.Data.results.filter(function (el) {return el.result.indexOf(option) > -1});
```

Comment: maybe you look for a different approach, like an object as hash table or a Set or Map.

Comment: @NinaScholz there are too many elements so I try to keep it simple

Comment: @NinaScholz If you understood the question, could you please make it clearer ?

Comment: actually i have no idea, what you want. maybe i need more examples of input and wanted output.

Comment: @NinaScholz now I have `el.result.indexOf('a')` where 'a' is `option` variable and I want something like `el.result.indexOf(['a', 'b'])`; make sense now?

Comment: @MarkusHayner, and what is the result of the (not working as intended) above check?

Comment: @MarkusHayner `indexOf` is returning an index. Is that what you need ? This will return you 2 indexes ?

Comment: @Weedoze, you get only one index of [`Array#indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf).

Comment: @NinaScholz I know. I meant if he want to use something like `indexOf(['a','b'])`. Does he want 2 indexes ?

Comment: @NinaScholz Now it actually look for only one element `a` but if that element is not in all my arrays it will not return that array.  `{["a","c","b"]}`  `{["a","c","b"]}`  `{["b","c","d"]}`  `{["a","c","e"]}`; so now it will return only first and second and fourth array. But I want to check if `a` and `b` are there so it will return only first and second because `a` and `b` are together only there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could filter the results array with a check for every element of `options`, if it is in the inner array of results.

```js
var results = [["a", "c", "b"], ["a", "c", "b"], ["b", "c", "d"], ["b", "c", "e"]],
    option = ["a", "b"],
    filtered = results.filter(function (a) {
        return option.every(function (b) {
            return a.indexOf(b) !== -1;
        });
    });
        
console.log(filtered);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what you're asking, but it sounds like you want to filter your results array by a collection of options? Something like this:

```
var options = ["a", "b"];
var results = ["c", "b", "a"];

var filtered = results.filter(result => options.indexOf(result) !== -1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You will need to reduce the list of options to remove the items you don't want. I didn't

```
reducedOptions = s.Data.results.reduce((acc, curr) => {
  if (el.result.indexOf(curr) > -1) {
    acc.push(curr) 
  }
  return acc;
}, [])
```

Also lodash has something built in for this called without

https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#without